# Django: Stripe & POST request

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am currently trying to implement Stripe Connect in my Django project. Stripe documentations states for Standard accounts:

> Assuming no error occurred, the last step is to use the provided code
>   to make a POST request to our access_token_url endpoint to fetch the
>   user’s Stripe credentials:

```
curl https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
   -d client_secret=sk_test_Dur3X2cOCwyjlf9Nr7OCf3qO \
   -d code="{AUTHORIZATION_CODE}" \
   -d grant_type=authorization_code
```

I now wonder how to send a POST request with Django without form & user action (clicking the submit button)?

Comment: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python look at this plugin, it has all the functionality,

Comment: You need to make a request from your server to Stripe's - it is not a request that the client makes in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Standard Connect relies on OAuth for its connection flow:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#oauth-flow

so you can use an OAuth python library like Rauth, as you mentioned, to handle the flow.

Also please note that Stripe Python library provides an implementation of the OAuth flow here:

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/a938c352c4c11c1e6fee064d5ac6e49c590d9ca4/stripe/oauth.py

You can see an example of its usage here:

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/f948b8b95b6df5b57c7444a05d6c83c8c5e6a0ac/examples/oauth.py

The example uses Flask not Django but should give you a good idea in terms of its use.

With regards to the advantages of using an existing OAuth implementation as opposed to implementing the calls directly yourself: one advantage I see is that your code would reuse a library that generally covers all different uses cases (e.g better error handling) and is also well tested.

Comment: You saved my day! I didn't know this example even exists, but it helped to implement it. (see below) Thanks a lot @psmvac

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @psmvac I could implement it the 'proper' way now using the oAuth of Stripe. Here some reference/example Django code if anyone is trying the same. Obviously, urls.py has to be configured. This is in my views.py:

```
def stripe_authorize(request):
    import stripe

    stripe.api_key = ''
    stripe.client_id = 'XYZ'

    url = stripe.OAuth.authorize_url(scope='read_only')
    return redirect(url)


def stripe_callback(request):
    import stripe
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    # import requests

    stripe.api_key = 'XYZ'
    ## import json  # ?

    code = request.GET.get('code', '')
    try:
        resp = stripe.OAuth.token(grant_type='authorization_code', code=code)
    except stripe.oauth_error.OAuthError as e:
        full_response = 'Error: ' + str(e)
        return HttpResponse(full_response)

    full_response = '''
<p>Success! Account <code>{stripe_user_id}</code> is connected.</p>
<p>Click <a href="/stripe-deauthorize?stripe_user_id={stripe_user_id}">here</a> to
disconnect the account.</p>
'''.format(stripe_user_id=resp['stripe_user_id'])
    return HttpResponse(full_response)


def stripe_deauthorize(request):
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    import stripe

    stripe_user_id = request.GET.get('stripe_user_id', '')
    try:
        stripe.OAuth.deauthorize(stripe_user_id=stripe_user_id)
    except stripe.oauth_error.OAuthError as e:
        return 'Error: ' + str(e)

    full_response = '''
<p>Success! Account <code>{stripe_user_id}</code> is disconnected.</p>
<p>Click <a href="/">here</a> to restart the OAuth flow.</p>
'''.format(stripe_user_id=stripe_user_id)
    return HttpResponse(full_response)
```